# What is wrong with this code please? (Form passing variables)

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have this code. Trying to pass form values from one internal page to the other and it's not working.

Here's the code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page One</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <form action="post" name="myform">
        <input type="text" value="" name="mytext" />
               <input type="submit" value="submit" />
               </form>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

//And page 2

```
<div data-role="page" id="page2">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Two</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <?php if (isset($_POST['mytext'])) {
  // do something with $_POST['value']
  echo 'it works'; } ?>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

It's basically not working ... no errors but no values either.

Comment: *"It's basically not working ... no errors but no values either."* That seems pretty odd. I suspect there's an error, but you're not watching for it. Far, far too many jQuery examples (and even jQuery API functions) omit error handling. **Always** be sure to handle the [`error`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) callback (either on each call, or globally via [`ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)). In this case, you should be seeing `error` get called with a 404, unless the URL you're posting the form to really is "post" (which is possible, just unlikely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the error is here:

```
<form action="post" name="myform">
        <input type="text" value="" name="mytext" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

action is supposed to be the handler of the form, either the same page or another one (where the php script that elaborates the form resides). POST is the **METHOD.** (which can be either GET or POST)

So it should be:

```
<form action="" method="POST" name="myform">  <!-- action = "" reloads the same page, otherwise you could write action="myphppage.php" or whatever -->
    <input type="text" value="" name="mytext" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your action should be the php script that is going to process your post variables and method should be post.

```
<form action="somefile.php" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="post" name="myform">
```

is wrong.

It should be something like:

```
<form method="post" name="myform" action="">
```

You need to send a POST method. The action is empty so it sends it to the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

The `'action'` should be the page that is the destination URL. You have mixed up `method="post"` with `action="post"`. Set the action as `"second_page.php".`

I didn't fully understand what you meant by internal page, but if it is the same page, only a different div, then leave the action as blank(`action=''`).

Comment: I suspect he's working with jQuery mobile, hence the internal page. It renders divs with `data-role="page"` as seperate pages in the final mobile app. From a pure structural POV, the code is all on the same 'page' though. Thought I'd clear that up for you :)