# Form passing vaiables via internal page not working

Tags: php, html

I am using this code. Trying to pass form values from one internal page to the other and it's not working.

Here's the full code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page One</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <form action="#page2" method="post" name="myform">
        <input type="text" value="" name="mytext" />
               <input type="submit" value="submit" />
               </form>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

//And page 2

```
<div data-role="page" id="page2">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Two</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <?php if (isset($_POST['mytext'])) {
  // do something with $_POST['value']
  echo 'it works'; } ?>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

It's basically not working ... no errors but no values either.

Comment: `#page2` doesn't make sense as an action without JavaScript. You want to specify a URL, don't you? Why did you tag this jquery-mobile, do you have jQuery code somewhere? In that case, you need to show that

Comment: Yes, but the target url is an internal page. I basically have a form on page 1 and goes to page2 and displays the result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is wrong with this code please? (Form passing variables)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321379/what-is-wrong-with-this-code-please-form-passing-variables)

Comment: Do you have ONE, or TWO pages? Or is it the same but javascript displays in in succession (as if they were 2 different)?

Comment: @Pekka: Even I tend to think that this might be a place of error, technically it does not depend on javascript. The URL `#page2` is a valid relative URL that will be resolved to the documents base URI. So normally this is the same page. This is totally unrelated to javascript. But obviously this is not for what it is used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
 <form action="#page2" method="post" name="myform">
```

to

```
 <form action="page2" method="post" name="myform">
```

Comment: That was not the problem. The problem is that the submitted value is not being passed to page2 from page 1 :o/

Comment: Then you are missing some code in your question, because that *is* the problem with the html you posted and the change does fix it.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that taking the # off doesn't solve the problem I have with the values not been passed.

Comment: I have tested your code using apache 2.2.17 and php 5.3.6 and this change does fix the problem. Thus I strongly suspect your question is not complete.